# Installing RVM - No Output, Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm on MacOS Sierra

brew doctor says no problem

xcode/gcc is installed

My first problem is [no response when I use curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwPnU.jpg).

And [here is what I get when I trace the installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGBvE.jpg).

After the installation is complete, I restart my terminal and try and use 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm', but I get an error 'No such file or directory'

I've tried to delete the directory and re-install a couple of times, but no luck.

EDIT: If I don't use -sSL, I get two lines of output, but still no luck: imgur.com/a/bxyLy

EDIT2: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3910 allows installation

Answer (score -2):

Use rbenv instead of rvm, rbenv is most suitable than rvm.

Homebrew setup:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

rbenv setup:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.4.0
rbenv global 2.4.0
ruby -v
```

Comment: rbenv and rvm are different tools. Denouncing the tool the question is about and describing a completely different tool doesn't help OP much nor is it a valid answer to their question.